# Convergence of exponential integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I have the following expression
$$
F(t)\equiv f(t)e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{f(t')}e^{t'}dt'
$$
with $f$ being a smooth positive function, bounded from above and below by some numbers.
I'm trying to prove that the term converges exponentially fast to 1. In the sense that
$$
\lvert F(t)-1\lvert\leq \mathcal{O}\left(e^{-t}\right)
$$
or something of similar fashion. Other bound or contradicting cases will also be helpful

Comment: If $f(t)=1/(|t|+1)$ then the convergence to $1$ is of rate $t^{-1}$.

Comment: @Gary I suspect the asker meant: bounded below by a positive constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be even and strictly increasing on $[0,\infty),$  for example $f(t)=(1+|t|)(2+|t|)^{-1}.$ Then for $t>0$ we get
$$f(t)e^{-t}\int\limits_{t/2}^t{1\over f(s)}e^s\,ds \ge 1-e^{-t/2}$$ and
$$f(t)e^{-t}\int\limits_0^{t/2}{1\over f(s)}e^s\,ds \ge  {f(t)\over f(t/2)}[e^{-t/2}-e^{-t}]$$ Hence
$$F(t)-1\ge  \left [{f(t)\over f(t/2)}-1\right]e^{-t/2}+O(e^{-t})$$
If $f(t)=(1+t)(2+t)^{-1}$ for $t>0,$ then
$${f(t)\over f(t/2)}-1={t\over (2+t)^2}$$
Thus $F(t)$ does not satisfy $|F(t)-1|\le O(e^{-t}).$

By applying the partition $[0,t-\log t],$ $[t-\log t,t]$ we can get  $F(t)-1\ge (t\log t)^{-1} +O(e^{-t}).$